# Graphs in Python with "Doing Math with Python"

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, anaconda

I'm having trouble trying to do Chapter 2 of "Doing Math with Python". I have Anaconda and Python 3.6.3 on Mac (10.13). I attempt to run one of the programs from Chapter 2, and I get a message saying, "No module named 'matplotlib'". How do I get past this?

Comment: Solution: install matplotlib

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/2.1.0/users/installing.html

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib` is not part of Python's standard library. You need to manually install it. This is quite easy. I'd suggest you follow this [offiical guide](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.0/users/installing.html). Try running this on your Terminal application:

```
python -mpip install -U pip
python -mpip install -U matplotlib
```

Comment: I'm getting this in response in the terminal:

[Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding

Current thread 0x00007fff89cac340 (most recent call first):
Abort trap: 6